# email not responsive in mobile with zurb email framework

Tags: css, email, zurb-ink

I realized that my email is still not responsive with zurb email framework, ink.
So, I tried the sample html in the download and ran through inliner tool.  The sample content also skewed to right.  What am I missing?  Here is the screenshot.  Sorry I am so new so cannot post image here.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22545218/Screenshot_2014-01-14-19-47-45.png

Per request, adding the source code.  There is no change that I made here.  It is straight from the download.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22545218/basic.html

Thanks,

Comment: You should post the code. We can't figure out what is wrong without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working, have you tried using the dev tools in Chrome or the Web Developer extension? Both show that your page is working responsively for me. http://d.pr/i/6B1v

Comment: I checked it again.  You are right.  I think the version that I got wasn't good for some reason, which is this one, https://www.dropbox.com/s/7hdjri6se2hr1tf/basic_112213.html Nov. 22 2013. The basic html in the question is from today.   The one that I downloaded on Jan. 7 had this issue and I can still reproduce it. They don't have a version mentioned so I assumed that it is same.   It seems like the newer version is now available in zurb and works fine.  Sorry I don't have enough points to give up vote. Thanks everyone for help.